# Generate multiple objects from a List

Tags: java

I have a method that takes a variable argument list.

```
getSome(Object... numbers);
```

I have a List holding all the parameters that I want to pass to the method.

```
ArrayList<Long> numbersList;
```

How can I achieve the following for ALL number objects in the list?

```
getSome(numbersList.get(0), numbersList.get(1), ... numbersList.get(numbersList.size()-1));
```

Comment: How about `getSome(numbersList.toArray())` or `getSome(numbersList.toArray(new Long[numbersList.size()]))`?

Comment: You should rewrite `getSome` to take a `List<Long>` then or add an overloaded method. why does your version take `Object...`?

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your list into an array:

```
getSome(numbersList.toArray(new Long[numbersList.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the method declaration :

```
getSome(Object... numbers);
```

You can pass an array to it.

You can use the [List#toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) method to transform the `List` to an `Long[]`:

```
numbersList.toArray(new Long[numbersList.size()]);
```